# HKU Thesis .cls

Tags: thesis

I am using the HKU Thesis document class, the `.cls` of which can be found [here](https://github.com/MacroYau/HKU-Thesis-LaTeX-Template/blob/master/hkuthesis.cls).  My problem is when I need to type

> man’s

In other document classes, I just type `man$’$s`.  But when I do that with this document class, it does not work. The compilation results in `man’  s`.

If I insist on using this `.cls`, might there be a work around? I just need anything that is acceptable as an apostrophe. It doesn't have to look exactly like `’`.

I hope I don't need to put any MWE. All the rest of the document is fine.

Comment: If you don't provide an MWE, you'll need to provide salient information in other ways. For instance, does the issue arise just with `man$'$s` or does it also occur with, say, `woman$'$s`, `boy$'$s`, and `girl$'$s`? Second, in which other document classes does this work (or, at least, work better)? Third, what are you trying to achieve by indicating the genitive form of a noun via the math-mode raised "prime" symbol instead of the ordinary text-mode apostrophe symbol? (To me, using math-mode primes instead of ordinary text-mode apostrophes is simply not appropriate, typographically speaking.)

Comment: `$'$` is wrong why are you using math mode???  just type `man's` if  you want man's.

Comment: Apologies for the trouble.  `man's` does work for this and other document classes. I will delete this entry after you've read this reply.  For the record, `man$’$s` in _report_ document class will produce the result I wanted. I used math mode because I read it from somewhere before, but I couldn't find it now. Anyway, thanks and apologies.

Comment: `$'$` doesn't make the extra space in hkuthesis either, did you discover where the space is coming from?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I made a mistake.  It doesn't create a space. It just disappears. The space is produced when I type `’`.  In other document classes, I wanted this symbol to appear as a normal apostrophe, and found somewhere that if I enclose it in a math mode, it will appear as it is.  And it worked. For some reason, I did not do the obvious which was to type `'`. I think I did and there was a problem that's why I resorted to `$’$`.

Comment: No, see the answer I posted which is using that class. `$'$` works just as in every other class and makes a math superscript prime (not an apostrophe!). If you are having issues in your real document that is due to code you have not shown. This is why you should always include a complete document that shows the issue.

Comment: oh you were using `$’$` with a right quote not `$'$` ah in that case you could get anything:-) That character is not set up for math mode at all, so what you get will be accidental, depending on the fonts used. and latex will warn `LaTeX Warning: Command \textquoteright invalid in math mode on input line 9.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost always need to provide an example. I can not reproduce the problem with extra space.

Using

```
\documentclass{hkuthesis}

\begin{document}

man's correct and works

man$'$s wrong but sort of half works

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

with no spurious space either with a normal apostrophe or with the mis-used math mode prime.

Comment: Thank you for your time.